# Linking a checkbox in google sheets to another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hello I am hosting a trivia night and I'm trying to make the scoreboard as simple as possible. I have a master sheet where all of my answers will go

[image]

I am trying to make it to where if the check box to the right is checked then the point value that is in the column next to it will be populated in the leader board on a separate sheet in the row with the corresponding name

[image]

I have tried using vlookups and if statements but I cannot get them to work together for some reason.

Comment: Can you show the functions you tried?

Comment: It would help if you provided a sample sheet, with sample data.  Perhaps your leader board can be monitoring the column with the checkboxes in the data sheet, and when checked, the leaderboard formula can copy the matching score value from the data sheet.